# migrate.exe, on a build server, wants to "start over" with migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Part of our automated build process involves running migrate.exe to update test databases to the latest version of the database.

The process is relatively simple:

1. Copy migrate.exe to the /bin folder of the project being compiled
2. Execute migrate.exe with the connection string (specified as part of the build definition).

An example of step two (redacted, obviously) would be:

```
migrate.exe Company.Data.dll /connectionString="Server=...;Database=...;User Id=...;Password=..." 
                             /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

where Company.Data.dll is the just-built output of the project being compiled on the build server.

This process has been in place for a few months and has been working fine. Until today.

Today, when the above command runs, migrate.exe tries to run ALL of the migrations - starting from the beginning - not just the new ones that were added. This obviously fails because it tries to create tables that already exist in the database. The problem occurs whether there are actually pending migrations or not.

I've confirmed that the database pointed to by the connection string shown in the log file is the correct one and that it has all of the appropriate entries in the __MigrationHistory table that should cause migrations to just enter what is missing.

If I pull down the code from source control, build it and run migrate.exe myself locally (with the same connection string) it acts appropriately (initially running just the migrations it should, then on subsequent tries saying there were no pending explicit migrations).

It would seem to me that as long as the connection string was pointed at the right database and the name of the DbContext-derived class used for EF matches what is in the __MigrationHistory table, migrate.exe should be able to find the entries and not run those migrations.

What else am I missing that I should look at?

**Update:**
I've just had this happen when pointed at a different database on the same server. Same "workaround" (running migrate.exe locally). Just interesting to note that it happened exactly the same way when pointed at a different database.

Comment: What are your test databases? SQL Server 2008?

Comment: That's strange. I know EF migrations sometimes get this on 2008. Usually dropping and re-creation of databases help, but this is a brute-force solution.

Comment: The thing that's killing me is that running the command locally against the same database works fine. So there's got to be a difference between my machine and the build server... I just can't figure out what it might be

Comment: Yeah, I had that, only not in Azure SQL. It works, until it does not. And then nothing can make it work. I've spent enough time on research about migrations (http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/03/inside_of_ef_migrations/) to just call it a magical glitch and move on to database recreation. It does not happen that often, but when it does, I never figured out why (http://stackoverflow.com/q/22648805/809357) -(

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the solution, I was getting the same issue. It turned out to be a SQL permissions issue.
The build server service user needs read/write and ddladmin permissions for the migration to work. 
In my situation, the dba had changed the permissions of the service user to ddladmin only but the migration process needs to read and write to the migration history tables.
Because it could not read the migration history, it assumed that it needed to apply all migrations.
It was the different permissions between my account and the build service account.
Hope this helps somebody.